# cd command only working when I put the slash after the directory name

Tags: directory-structure, cd-command

I am new to Linux and working through Dion's course for Linux+. I'm currently on Permissions and Sticky Bits, and have run into an issue I can't figure out.

The assignment asks to create a directory called Crypto, and then change the directory permissions. The prompt shows the examples being completed as a root user.

I created the directory using the following command: mkdir Crypto, and when I use the ls -al command I can see the directory was successfully created.

The example prompt then instructs to change to another user and execute the following command: cd /Crypto

I receive the "No such file or directory" error when I enter the command as instructed, but I figured out that if I enter the command as such: cd Crypto/ I am able to switch directories.

What am I doing wrong? What is the difference between "cd /Crypto" and "cd Crypto/"?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you include a link to the course [in your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/755851/edit)?

Comment: The title is a misinterpretation. It's not about the slash after the name, it's about the (lack of the) slash before the name.

Comment: I’m guessing it’s [this course](https://www.diontraining.com/courses/comptia-linux)...

Comment: It's very likely the course's `cd` command is missing a period, and should be:  `cd ./Crypto`.

Answer (score 3):

The command `cd /Crypto` will change the working directory to a directory called `Crypto` located at `/`, the root of the directory structure.  This will fail if there is no directory called `Crypto` in `/`.

The command `cd Crypto/` (or the equivalent `cd Crypto` or `cd ./Crypto`) will change the working directory to a directory called `Crypto` located in the current directory.  The trailing slash in `Crypto/` serves no real purpose (it would possibly serve a purpose under some circumstances, but not here).

Your command `cd /Crypto` would have succeeded if you had created the directory in the root of the directory tree, which possibly might have been the intention of the exercise.  You would have created the directory in the root of the directory tree had you done `cd /` before `mkdir Crypto`, or if you had used `mkdir /Crypto` (from wherever in the directory hierarchy).

The dot in `cd ./Crypto` means "the current directory", and `..` means "the parent directory".